# how to use nested std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, stdbind

I have a functional object `test_id` and a structure `Node`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

struct test_id : std::unary_function< int, bool>
{
      typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator iterator;
      iterator first, last;
      explicit test_id(std::vector<int> const& v_id) : first(v_id.begin()), last(v_id.end()){}
      bool operator()(int id)const{ return std::binary_search(first, last, id); }
};

struct Node
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
    //...and a lot of members.

   //-------------------
   std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Node> > children;
};

int main()
{

     Node node; 
     // initialize it with some values
     node.id = 0;
     node.name = "root";
     srand(time(NULL));
     for(int i= 0; i < 100; ++i)
     {
        std::unique_ptr<Node> ch (new Node );
        ch->id = static_cast<int>( rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * 100 );
        ch->name = "children";
        node.children.push_back( std::move(ch) );
     }

   //............
   std::vector<int> existing_ids; 
    // initialize it with some values.
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      if ( i % 3 == 1) existing_ids.push_back(i);

    //sort it
    std::sort(existing_ids.begin(), existing_ids.end() );

   // Now, I want remove elements from the children, where id is in existing_ids vector.
   node.children.erase( 
    std::remove_if( 
         node.children.begin(), 
         node.children.end(), 
         std::bind(test_id(existing_ids), std::bind(&Node::id, std::placeholders::_1) )//--> compile error
         ), 
   node.children.end() );
}
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 sp1.
**I know I could use lambda, but my question is: how to use std::bind in this situation?**

EDIT: this compiles fine, so I can extract id from Node:

```
//EDIT:
std::vector<int> all_ids;
std::transform(
   node.children.begin(), 
   node.children.end(), 
   std::back_inserter(all_ids), 
   std::bind(&Node::id, std::placeholders::_1) 
);
```

Comment: @Brian. I think that I can extract `id` member. But I can't re-direct it to functor's argument.

Comment: What's missing though is a way to *compose* the `id` extraction function with the `test_id(existing_ids)` function.

Comment: I don't know it), I want know it !!!

Comment: I still think you can't do this with *only* `std::bind`. Why do you insist on doing it this way?

Comment: Your code [compiles and runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15e8ba5cc019adfe) on gcc and clang. This is probably some MSVC bug you're dealing with.

Comment: Voted to close because it seems to have been a compiler bug from 10 years ago, and without a quote of the mysterious "compile error" this post seems to be fairly useless for posterity.